# Why did my font suddenly change?

Tags: html, css, fonts

I was doing some simple coding and my site's font suddenly changed. I never set a font-family, so the font was a default serif. Then it changed to a monospace font. The weirdest thing is that the previously coded text stayed the same serif font. I have no idea what It could be. I also apologize for the poor design, it's a WIP. Here's a screenshot:

[image]
As you can see, the bottom and the left text are all in that monospace, but the right isn't quite working

CSS:

```
    html,body               {
                            width: 100%;
                            height: 100%;
                            font-family: serif;

    }


    body                {
                            background-color: #00adc4;
    } 


    .center             {
                            text-align: center;
    }

/* Home */

    /* Logo */

        img.logo            {
                                width: 8%;
                                height: auto;
                                float: left;
        }

    /* Logo */
    /*Navigation Bar */

        nav                 {
                                background-color: turquoise;
                                border-radius: 10px;
                                width: 80%;
                                display: block;
                                margin: 0px auto;
        }

        nav a               {
                                text-decoration: none;
                                color: teal;
                                font-size: 60%;
                                text-shadow: 0.5px -0.5px;
                                display: inline;
                                margin: 2%;
                                text-align: center;
        }

        nav a:visited       {
                                color: teal;
        }


    /*Navigation Bar */

    /* Header */

        h1.header           {
                                text-align: center;
                                font-size: 150%;
        }
    /* Header */

    /* Main Content */


        .main               {
                                border: 1px solid black;
                                border-radius: 5px;
                                background-color: #00dddd;
                                width: 40%;
                                float: right;
                                max-height: 40% !important;
                                overflow-y: auto;
                                margin: 2%;
                                padding: 1%;
        }


    /* Main Content */

    /* Sidebars */


        aside.aside1                {
                                height: 20%;
                                width: 40%;
                                margin: 2%;
                                padding: 1%;
                                /* background-color: teal; */
                                /* border: 1px solid black; */
                                float: left;
                                border-radius: 5px;
        }


        h3.specials         {
                                margin: 0%;
                                text-align: center;
        }

        /* Sidebar Images */

        img.thumbnail_1     {
                                width: 30%;
                                height: auto; 
                                margin: 0% 2%;
        }

        img.thumbnail_2     {
                                width: 20%;
                                height: auto;
                                margin: 0% 2%;
        }

        img.thumbnail_3     {
                                width: 27%;
                                height: auto;
                                margin: 0% 2%;
        }
        /* Sidebar Images */


    /* Sidebars */

    /* Mailing List */
        div.coupon          {

                                height: 20%;
                                width: 40%;
                                background-color: teal;
                                border-radius: 3px;
                                -webkit-animation: animation 2s;
                                animation: animation 2s;
                                margin-left: 3%;
        }

    /* Mailing Liist */

    /* Multimedia */

        audio.contest           {
                                    width: 100%;
        }

    /* Multimedia */

/* Home */
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Special Deals - The Jumpin' Juice Company</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="finalmobile.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and ( min-width: 30em )" href="finaltablet.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and ( min-width: 48em )" href="final.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="project.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img src="images/logo.jpg" alt="Logo" title="Jumpin' Juice" class="logo">
        <header>
            <h1 class="header">The Jumpin' Juice Company</h1>
        </header>
        <hr>
        <nav>
            <a href="index.html">Home</a>
            <a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a>
            <a href="faq.html">FAQ</a>
            <a href="signup.html">Coupons</a>
            <a href="specials.html">Specials</a>
            <a href="locations.html">Locations</a>
        </nav>
        <hr>    
        <section class="main">
            <h3 class="news">News</h3>
            <h4 style="color: grey;"><b>Annual Audio Contest</b></h4>
            <p style="font-size: small; color: black;">This contest is a chance for you to win a year's supply of juice, all on us. Submit the best music relating to juice to win!</p>
            <h5>Last Year's Winner:</h5>
            <audio class="contest" controls>
                <source src="multimedia/AmTronic_-_Caribbean_Dub.mp3">
                <source src="multimedia/AmTronic_-_Caribbean_Dub.ogg">
                Your browser doesn't support .mp3 or .ogg extensions
            </audio>
            <p style="font-size: small; color: red;">The deadline for entries has been reached<code></p>
        </section>
        <aside class="aside1">
            <h3 class="specials">Specials!</h3>
            <a href="specials/orangejuice.html" target="_blank"><img class="thumbnail_1" src="images/juices/orange_juice.jpg" alt="orange juice" title="Orange Juice"></a>
            <a href="specials/cranberryjuicetea.html" target="_blank"><img class="thumbnail_2" src="images/juices/cranberry_juice_tea.jpg" alt="cranberry juice tea" title="Cranberry Juice Tea"></a>
            <a href="specials/berry_madness.html" target="_blank"><img class="thumbnail_3" src="images/juices/berrymadness.jpg" alt="berry madness" title="Berry Madness"></a>
            <p style="font-size: 50%; display: inline;">Orange Juice</p>
            <p style="font-size: 40%; display: inline;">Cranberry Juice Tea</p>
            <p style="font-size: 50%; display: inline;">Berry Madness</p>
        </aside>
        <br><br><br><br><br><br>
        <div class="coupon">
            <p class="animation">Check out this</p>
        </div>
        <br><br><br>
        <footer>
            <p style="font-size: small; text-align: center;">&#169; Jumpin' Juice Company, 2017</p>
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why not just set the default font? `body { font-family: serif; }`

Comment: I already tried that yet nothing changed

Comment: We can't debug a screenshot. Show us your code.

Comment: Post your CSS here

Comment: Can you post your page HTML too

Comment: @itodd sorry my bad

Comment: You have a stray `<code>` tag in you mark-up. Remove it as this is what is causing your problem

Comment: You should be using a HTML5 validator for your code. It will help pick up any markup issues: https://html5.validator.nu/

Answer (score 1):

You are only using serif as your default font-family.
It's better to use commonly used font combinations.

For serif fonts:

```
font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
```

For sans-serif fonts:

```
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
```

More details here: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_websafe_fonts.asp

---

You also can use Google Web Fonts.

Here is an example with Roboto Font:

On your HTML file:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
```

On your CSS file:

```
font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
```

More information about how to use Google web Fonts:
https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/getting_started